# Electron notifications shows with two icons in OSX (mac) instead of one

Tags: macos, electron

I'm trying to make my electron based app push notifications to work normally in Mac without a success.

In windows notification looks as the following:

[image]

But in Mac it shows my icon twice (once the app icon (blue) and the programmable one (white)):

[image]

My code is pretty simple:

```js
class NotificationSender {
    private readonly icon: NativeImage;

    constructor() {  
        this.icon = nativeImage.createFromPath(Config.iconPath);
    }
    
    public show(title: string, msg: string) {
        new Notification({
            title: title,
            body: msg,
            icon: this.icon,
        }).show();
    }
}

export const notificationsSender = new NotificationSender();
```

I know that I can just remove the programmable picture, but I wish to remove the app icon (blue) and keep the programable (white).

How can I do it?